# C# get property value type<T> from a class by name, do I need reflection?

Tags: c#, class

This might be already answered but I couldn't find a specific answer for my use case.

I have a class which has several properties defined as follows:

```
class Test {
  public myOwnType<int> TestProp1 { get; set; }
  public myOwnType<decimal> TestProp2 { get; set; }
  public myOwnType<ulong> TestProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

And I would like to add a method to this class which returns the value of that property, but whatever that type is, could be `myOwnType<int>` or `myOwnType<whatever>`.

Something that looks like this

```
  var cl = new Class();
  var p1 = cl['TestProp1']; // would be of type myOwnType<int>
  var p2 = cl['TestProp2']; // would be of type myOwnType<decimal>
```

I need this for this specific class and I believe I should need reflection, I am looking for the most performant way of retrieving that value and not return a generic object.

Comment: This looks rather like a case where I would expose a Dictionary.

Comment: You're not going to be able to get exactly what you're asking for. `var` is "compiler, please figure out the correct type for this variable" but there's no way for the compiler (or us) to correctly deduce the type based on an indexer (assuming you pass an actual string) which could return "anything".

Comment: I cant see the use case from your code alone but assuming the types are not that complex, how about a very simple solution then figure out if you need anything more complex later?

Something like TryGetPropValue<T>(string propName, out T value) with a switch case inside

Comment: @arynaq the use case is that I dont know exactly what myOwnType<T> is , I dont know the T, I know its a property of myOwnType but I dont know nor I care if its myOwnType<int> or myOwnType<long> , they both behave the same and both have the same methods in them.

Comment: It is not clear to me what the actual goal is. Do you want to refer to properties by a runtime specified name? call methods/properties om a generic type? If the later you could just make your generic type implement a non generic interface.

Comment: You can just use TestProp1.GetType() to get the outer Type and then on the Type returned look at GenericTypeArgument[0] to see the inner type (the template T type).

    `var test = new Class3<int>();
    var outerType = test.GetType();
    var genericType = outerType.GenericTypeArguments[0];`

Comment: If you don't know or care about the `T` in `myOwnType<T>`, only about the non-T-related functionality, Wouldn't it be possible to have a non-generic (abstract?) base class `myOwnType` which contains all the non-generic functionality and then let `myOwnType<T>` inherit from that and only contain the `T`specific things?

Comment: _"the use case is that I dont know exactly what myOwnType<T> is"_ - but you actually do. If you request property 1 it's `int`, property 2 it's `decimal`, ...

Comment: Perhaps `myOwnType<T>` (which even in sample code should follow naming conventions to avoid distracting attention from the real issue - just like your string literals should use `"` instead of `'`) should implement a non-generic interface? Then you could just write an indexer declared to return that interface instead.

Comment: I am still unsure if we are solving the right problem. If you need to (do you?) access by name, why do we have properties, not a dictionary? Why do they have different numerical types when you obviously need to iterate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is the thing: I get what you are trying to do, but i do not think its really possible. It would be very helpfull if we knew what methods your type has, so that we can base our attempts on that. But for know this is all I can really give you. As many users have said in the comments some base class or interface would be the best thing to do here. Since I do not know what your type needs to be able to do Ive kept things very simple, and there will most likely be a need for edits once we get more info.

```
public class NewTests
{
    public void TestCase()
    {
        TestClass TC = new TestClass();
        var p1 = TC["TestProp1"];
    }
}


public class TestClass
{
    public MyOwnType? this[string propName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (propName == "TestProp1")
            {
                return TestProp1;
            }
            else if (propName == "TestProp2")
            {
                return TestProp2;
            }
            else if (propName == "TestProp3")
            {
                return TestProp3;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyOwnType<int> TestProp1 { get; set; }
    public MyOwnType<decimal> TestProp2 { get; set; }
    public MyOwnType<ulong> TestProp3 { get; set; }

    public TestClass()
    {
        TestProp1 = new(1);
        TestProp2 = new(2);
        TestProp3 = new(3);
    }
}

public interface MyOwnType
{
    public void FunMethod();
}

public class MyOwnType<T>: MyOwnType
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public MyOwnType(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public void FunMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

This wont make var a MyOwnType int but a MyOwnType and when you use the defined Methods theyll still behave according to the type. Again we do need more Info, so we need to know what Methods your Type has and what you wanna do with it.

Comment: I see, that makes a bit more sense I guess.
The idea is that, I can call FunMethod() on whatever sub-type  is, because they all have it, So i guess I should define an interface or a base class as mentioned above.

Comment: Is there any way I can make a return method MyOwnType<T> and change the T part  of the actual T of that property? not sure thats make sense. 
Or define a return type MyOwnType<ANY>

Comment: So you mean That FunMethod returns the Objects its in? So that Propert1.FunMethod() returns a MyOwnType<int>?

Comment: Might I ask why you want to get the properties using a string and not directly?

Comment: this object will have 100+ properties, all of type MyOwnType , but some of them will be MyOwnType<int> and some MyOwnType<decimal> and so so, only numbers are allowed , and I need to write a generic method that will output the value of its properties, getting them 1 by 1 by their name is cumbersome

Comment: So youll have like a List with all the names and then a loop that gets the falue for each name?

Comment: yep, exactly, and "I know" the properties will exist and will be of MyOwnType<whatever> for sure, there is no need to play safe, if its on the list, it will be defined and valid.
So far I went along with a dynamic variable, I bet its not ideal but I know the methods it will have

Comment: Are you on .Net 8+?

Comment: @Fildor indeed, 8

Comment: @TotalZero     So heres the thing in this case we will never be able to really get var to myOwnType<int> because var needs to know what it is AT compile time. During compile time it wont check your List and know what itll get so we will always have some generic between us.

Comment: I was just wondering if the new interfaces could help ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1?view=net-8.0

Comment: And another question: what is done with the values? Calculations? (String-) Output?

Comment: Say out of interest why have 100+ propertiest instead of some lists?

Comment: ^^ exactly. That made me think "oh, deeper design problem", too.

Comment: @Fildor my type class MyOwnType<T> actually implements INumber<T>, and operations done with the values are Outputs basically.

Comment: @SMSTJ good point, I may need to design this better, but anyhow and list of properties could only be of type MyOwnType<int> and another list for the ones of MyOwnType<decimal> and so on, there is no MyOwnType<generic>

Comment: thanks a lot to you both for taking the time to answer my paranoia, I better get back to the board and change the underlaying design.... :/

Comment: I mean even if things dont work out the way you wanted to questions like theese still have a lot of upsides. As long as people actually try to answer your question without juts sazing "Dumb idea do it different" it can get you a lot of insight into the topic of in this case generics and interfaces. Id still reccomend that on your off time you still experiment with your original idea. It wont work BUT youll gain knowledge that might be usefull later on

Comment: Also shameless little request: if you fell like it you could mark this as the correct answer^^

Comment: @SMSTJ indeed, as it actually was, and concur with you that it gave me a lots of better ideas ! thanks a lot !

Comment: You are very much welcome^^

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use reflection to achieve the desired result but, keep in mind that using reflection might have performance implications, so use it sensibly.
Here is the example.

```
public class myOwnType<T>
{
    // Assuming this is your class definition
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Test
{
    public myOwnType<int> TestProp1 { get; set; }
    public myOwnType<decimal> TestProp2 { get; set; }
    public myOwnType<ulong> TestProp3 { get; set; }

    //get the property value based on its name
public object GetPropertyValue(string propertyName)
{
    var property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

    if (property == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found");
    }

    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(this);

    if (propertyValue == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Check if the property type is myOwnType<T> and use reflection to get the 'Value' property
    Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
    if (propertyType.IsGenericType && propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(myOwnType<>))
    {
        Type innerType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var valueProperty = propertyType.GetProperty("Value");
        return valueProperty.GetValue(propertyValue);
    }
    return propertyValue;
}
     
}
```

and usage :

```
 var cl = new Test();
       var p1 = cl.GetPropertyValue("TestProp1");
```

Comment: But that implies knowing that TestProp1 is of subtype<int> , and I don't know that, I know its of type myOwnType but I don't know the inside type (or subtype)

Comment: @TotalZero If you don't know the type of myOwnType<T> at compile time and you want to retrieve it dynamically using reflection, you can modify the GetPropertyValue method to handle the case. The code is updated, please review it. & let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: This seems to be a very nice solution, except for the fact that they want the return value to not be object but their own type